# When is better to complete a save of Seekbar onProgressChanged vs. onStopTrackingTouch?

Tags: android

I have a Seekbar and I want to save the state to database when the progress is changed.

I am wondering in which event to put my code [onProgressChanged](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html)  vs. [onStopTrackingTouch](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to disagree with both mbaird and jqpubliq, for one simple reason: they assume the user is using a touchscreen.

Most Android devices have touchscreens. Not all will. For example, there are firms developing Android set-top boxes (think Android equivalents of Roku or Boxee Box). Most televisions are not touchscreens.

Now, if you want your application to only be usable with a touchscreen -- and you have set the appropriate `<uses-configuration>` elements in your manifest -- `onStopTrackingTouch()` may be reliable for detecting a progress change.

Personally, I would update the database on neither `onProgressChanged()` nor `onStopTrackingTouch()`, but at the point when the user does something positive to indicate they want to persist the current screen's contents -- pressing the BACK button, clicking a Save button, etc. But I certainly would not rely on `onStopTrackingTouch()` unless you are developing a touchscreen-only app.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `onProgressChanged` if you need to update any elements of the UI as the user is sliding the progress bar.

I would wait for `onStopTrackingTouch` to actually update the database.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have reason to believe that the application will often crash in the middle of the gesture and you need to save where the user was at that time, I would recommend `onStopTrackingTouch`.